# Uploading files in Spring+Wicket

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, wicket

What are the steps required for enabling a Java web application (Developed using Spring + Wicket) to accept client file uploads to a specific directory on the server.
While Googling for answers to this question I see suggestions that /WEB-INF/some-directory should be used as the upload location?
Is the reason for this best practice?
Is this location writable by the web application?
What happens to this location when a new version of the web application is deployed?
Can/Should any other directory be used?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two possible reasons for the use of a subdirectory of WEB-INF:

- it is not visible through HTTP
- your application typically has write access to it

I would rather recommend using a configurable, external directory (e.g configured in a context parameter or en application config file); this way you have fine grained control over the permissions of the directory.

AFAIK, file upload in Wicket is provided by the [FileUploadField](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/upload/FileUploadField.html) component, which gives you a [FileUpload](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/upload/FileUpload.html) object that you can [writeTo](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/upload/FileUpload.html#writeTo%28java.io.File%29) a file on your server.

You might also want to configure/check the maximum size for the files you want to accept. In Tomcat, this is done through the maxPostSize attribute of a Connector (see [The HTTP Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html))

Comment: Storing uploaded files in webapp's own file structure is a big **no-no** because 1) This doesn't work when the container isn't configured to expand the WAR. 2) All uploaded files get lost whenever you redeploy the WAR or even whenever you restart the server.